# Find a bounded operator $T$ with spectrum $\sigma(T) = \mathbb{C}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I have been stuck at question 10B.5 from Axler's Measure, Integration and Real Analysis [(MIRA)](https://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf) for a long time. Could anyone please give me some hints or post a solution? The exercise reads

> Give an example of a bounded operator $T$ on a normed vector space such that for every $\alpha \in F$, the operator $T− \alpha I$ is not invertible.

Here, $F$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

If the vector space is a Banach space, then $T − \alpha I$ is invertible for $\alpha > \|T\|$ (this is result 10.35b in the book), so I have been considering non-complete spaces. But I haven't had any luck so far.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When Axler's text says "bounded operator", he means an _endomorphism_: a bounded operator from $V$ and _to_ $V$ as well.  (Not a hint, just a clarification to other answerers.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not worrying about boundedness for the moment, take $V = F[x]$ and let $T : V \to V$ be the linear map given by multiplication by $x$. Then $T - \alpha I$ is the operator which multiples by $x - \alpha$, which is never invertible because the result is always a polynomial of positive degree so in particular can never be $1$. ($T$ and its close relative the derivative $D = \frac{d}{dx}$ are a great source of counterexamples in infinite-dimensional linear algebra. $T$ is injective but not surjective, $D$ is surjective but not injective, $T$ has no eigenvalues, the only eigenvalue of $D$ is $0$ but $D$ isn't nilpotent...)

It remains to figure out a norm to put on $F[x]$ with respect to which $T$ is bounded. But this is straightforward: we can make $F[x]$ an inner product space (not a Hilbert space) in which the monomials $x^i$ are orthonormal, so that the norm of a polynomial $\sum f_i x^i$ is $\sum | f_i |^2$. Then $T$ is an isometry, so $\| T \| = 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: The operator is equivalent to the shift operator $S$ acting on a subspace $\mathcal{F}$ of $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}_0)$ consisting of sequences with finitely many nonzero terms. The operator $S$ acts as $$S(x_0,x_1,\ldots )=(0,x_0,x_1,\ldots )$$ This operator is also bounded with respect to $\ell^p$ norm and $\lambda I-S$ is not invertible as the operator from $\mathcal{F}$ to itself.

Comment: Another way to norm $F[x]$ naturally is to consider it as a subset of $C[0,1]$ with the max norm.